# Of questions/answers I've downvoted, how many have been deleted?

Tags: support, downvotes

I would like to know how efficient my downvotes are on Stack Overflow.

Is it possible to calculate a ratio (`nbDownvotes / nbDeletedDownvotes`)?

Comment: For answers: check how often you got +1 reputation.

Comment: I don't think you can do this reliably, deleted post are also removed from your vote history.  There is an indirect way to do it.  Go to your profile > Activity > summary shows total number of downvotes at the bottom right.  Then profile > Activity > votes > downvote shows the specific posts you downvoted but still survive.  Take the number of pages x 30 + posts on last page.  The problem however is that I'm fairly sure your total downvotes get reset when you get a rep recalc, that's been happening a lot lately due to the Docs rep misery.

Comment: @HansPassant Seems interesting, but I don't understand the *"x 30 + last page"* part. Could you explain a bit more your idea? (as an answer if you want)

Comment: @Mistalis: each page lists 30 entries, except for the last page, so `number of pages * 30` is a rough estimate, but you need to adjust for the number of items on that last page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep, but as far as I understand the total is also shown above "XXX Votes Cast", isn't it?

Comment: @Mistalis: duh, yes, that number is the total for posts still visible.. :-D No need count pages here at all.

Comment: In `Profile > Activity > Summary` I've **370** downvotes, and **185** in `Activity > Votes > Downvotes`. So **50%** (`185 / 370 * 100`) of my downvotes have been deleted, right?

Comment: The other way around, that many downvotes have *not* resulted in deletion.  Well, happens to be the same number for you of course, not for others.  Do keep the recalc in mind, it is *at least* 50%.  But with 50% you almost surely did not get a recalc so you can assume it is accurate.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not entirely sure that recalcs affect that number. I regularly trigger a recalc (repcapping plus downvoting does that to you) and I don't see any fluctuation in the numbers.